# Arrange CakePHP plugins into subfolders

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins

I've noticed some people mentioning a similar request for controllers and sometimes models, but I've been unable to find anything on arranging plugins in subfolders.

I want...

```
/app
    /Plugin
        /Modules
            /Form
                /Controller
            /Gallery
                /Controller
        /SomeStandardPlugin
            /Controller
```

..so that I can keep all the CMS functionality specific plugins separate.

I've tried:

```
CakePlugin::load('Form');
CakePlugin::load('Modules/Form');
CakePlugin::load('../Plugin/Modules/Form');
```

No matter which of the above I try, when I attempt to make use of the controller in one of the plugins, it says:

`Error: FormsController could not be found.`

`Error: Create the class FormsController below in file: app\Controller\FormsController.php`

(Which would be fine if I didn't want it in a plugin!)

The CookBook didn't mention anything about it either - is it just not supported or am I missing something?

FYI: I'm using CakePHP v2.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The argument for `CakePlugin::load` is not a path

The first argument for this function, is the *name* of a plugin. This is the correct way to load a plugin:

```
CakePlugin::load('Name');
```

But it will only work if the plugin exists in a [location configured using App::build](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#adding-paths-for-app-to-find-packages-in)

As such, to organize plugins into subfolders, it's necessary to declare all paths that contain *a* plugin:

```
// append app/Plugin/Modules to the path to look for plugins
App::build(array(
    'Plugin' => array(
        APP . 'Plugin/Modules'
     )
));
```

Comment: I've tried this in my bootstrap in `app/config/` and the AppController `beforeFilter()`, but no luck still. I have (in the relative `Controller` folder a `FormsAppController.php` and `FormsController.php` each file containing a class of the filename, extending `AppController`. I created a `FormsAppModel` as well as per the instructions on the CakePHP Cookbook

Comment: Does it work with the plugin in a conventional location (i.e. is your problem related to paths or something else)? If you're using 2.2.3, `app/config` is not where Cake is looking for config files. by the time the code reaches the beforeFilter - it's in the process of rendering a "missing whatever" exception, that's way too late :).

Comment: It doesn't... not sure why I didn't try that before -.-  So it's actually just a borked plugin, at the moment rather than a plugin in the wrong place lol. On your other note though, where should your `App::build` code go? My database and other configs are being read from `app/Config` so I assumed that would need to go there as well.

Comment: config !== Config. For more info refer to the docs: [plugins need to be loaded manually in app/Config/bootstrap.php.](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html)

Comment: yea just noticed it mention the bootstrap.php (I know it's "Config" I just didn't bother capitalising it in my comment as I assumed it was clear which folder I meant, my apologies for the confusion)

Comment: Done it! Moved the functions into the bootstrap.php and created the required views and it's all working now! Thanks for the help.